# oracle crash - not starting

Tags: windows, oracle

We have a 
Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise x64
Oracle 10.2.0.3 
Adempiere - ERP

1. We had a power breakdown at 03.00 AM.
2. At 07.30 AM we started the server
3. At 08.00 our colleagues observed that the ERP is not functioning
4. We started Adempiere
5. ERP was not able to connect to Oracle DB
6. We entered EM Console and we checked the DB status
7. The listener was functional - up and running
8. DB was shotdown in progress
9. We tried to abort shot down via SQL Plus using command :
   shutdown abort
10. Nothing happen
11. We tried shutdown - no result
12. We tried shutdown immediate - no result
13. Then we made Windows Shutdown from start menu
14. After restart of the server we checked in Windows Services.MSC the Oracle running services
15. Oracle JoobscheduleORCL was disabled, the rest were running. We set this one on automatic
16. The listener was functional - up and running
17. DB was shotdown in progress
18. We tried to abort shot down via SQL Plus using command :
    shutdown abort
19. Nothing happen
20. We tried shutdown - no result
21. We tried shutdown immediate - no result
22. We tried to restart the Oracle Services with no result
23. We searched on the forum.oracle.com and we found out that the problem could be that the undotablespace is corrupted.
24. We tried to fix the table
25. We used the following command line :

alter database datafile  'xxxxx\undotbs01.dbf'  offline drop;

http://www.dbas-oracle.com/2011/06/recovery-from-undo-tablespace-block.html

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5669213349582

1. The current situation is :

   ```
   SQL> startup
   ORA-01081: cannot start already-running ORACLE - shut it down first

   SQL> shutdown immediate
   ORA-24324: service handle not initialized
   ORA-24323: value not allowed
   ORA-01092: ORACLE instance terminated. Disconnection forced

   SQL> startup
   ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
   ```

Comment: Is the OracleService<DB Sid> currently running?

Comment: Yes, it is running.

Comment: And, in its current state, try "shutdown abort;", exit sqlplus, reconnect with "sqlplus / as sysdba", startup.

Comment: Follow REW's suggestion.  Also note that `SHUTDOWN ABORT` does not mean abort the shutdown, see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/start003.htm#i1006611

Comment: It would be useful to post the alert.log file

Answer (score 1):

Be sure the ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID environment variables are correctly set. Then run `sqlplus / AS SYSDBA` as a user who is a member of the `oradba` group on the computer.

Get the machine down forcibly:

```
SHUTDOWN ABORT
```

Start it up, but try not to let stuff run wild:

```
STARTUP RESTRICT
```

Shut it down more gracefully. Don't stop until recovery is complete.

```
SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE
```

Start it up.

```
STARTUP
```